# What's the purpose of many ids in an iOS launch storyboard that just displays a simple centered image?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I have this code for an iOS launch storyboard:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="15505" 
          targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" launchScreen="YES" 
          useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="01J-lp-oVM">
    <device id="retina5_5" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="15509"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="EHf-IW-A2E">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="01J-lp-oVM" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Llm-lL-Icb"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="xb3-aO-Qok"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="Ze5-6b-2t3">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="736"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="LaunchIcon" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1864">
                                <rect key="frame" x="131" y="292" width="152" height="152"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="152" id="2074"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="152" id="2075"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="whiteColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="1864" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="Ze5-6b-2t3" secondAttribute="centerX" id="2284"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="1864" secondAttribute="centerY" id="2285"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="iYj-Kq-Ea1" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="53" y="375"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

The code seems bloated, filled  with IDs and possibly other things I do not need as all it does is display an image in the center.

Can someone give me some suggestions on how I can clean up this code and what I could remove.

Comment: I think they are needed. You display an image in the center, that means the image is added to a view, then the view belongs to a viewController, the viewController  is owned by a scene. Each id there represent a view, an image, a viewController, a scene or a constraint. They will be used internally by Apple.

Comment: Why are you trying to clean this code anyway ?

Answer (score 6):

The Storyboard format is a human-readable format (`XML`) but it's not open. Unlike `XAML`, where you can define UI layout without having a designer, Storyboards have to be created with the Storyboard designer (shipped with `Xcode`). I wouldn't recommend editing the Storyboard file manually in a text/xml editor because they will be overridden by the Storyboard designer once you open it.

All the identifiers you see inside have an internal storyboard format defined by `Apple` and used by the Storyboard designer to link elements, containers, and constraints.

I agree that Storyboards introduce less flexibility and a lot of challenges in a multi-team-member environment because they are editable in the designer only:

- one person can introduce changes at a time
- conflicts resolution
- change tracking

Thus, from time to time you will see developers switching to `code-only` approach and define the UI in the source code only (`Objective-C` or `Swift`) by creating all the controls and layouts programmatically.

Comment: Is it possible to convert the element ID into a more human readable variable? It's really hard to follow along the code if it's only the random generated id that is being referenced all the time.